# DataFrame labyrinth game solution?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I wanted to test my pands skills by creating a labyrinth game, basically create a dataframe with 0s and 1s, where the 0s represent an open square and the 1s represent a wall:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, (10,11)))

       0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1
   2   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1
   3   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
   4   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0
   5   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1
   6   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
   7   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0
   8   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0
   9   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0
```

The idea was to check if it was possible to go from column 0 to column 10 just passing by the 0s, just horizontally or vertically. My solution was (if there's a two in the last column it can be solved):

```
def expand(col):
    if col[0]==0: last0= 0
    else: last0= 'x'
    for ind in range(1, len(col)):
        if col[ind]==0 and (last0=='x'): last0 = ind
        if col[ind]==1: last0 = 'x'
        if col[ind]==2 and last0!='x':
            for val in range(last0, ind):
                col[val]=2
        if col[ind-1]==2 and col[ind]==0: col[ind]=2
    return col


def sol(df):
    df[0] = df.apply(lambda x: 2 if x[0]==0 else x[0], axis=1)
    for col in range(1, len(df.T)):
        df[col] = df.apply(lambda x: 2 if x[col-1]==2 and x[col]==0 else x[col], axis=1)
        df[col] = expand(df[col])
sol(df)
```

Honestly, I was pretty proud of it's efficiency until I realized it isn't a complete solution. It only fills the 2s to the right, so if a labyrinth required going right, then up, left and right again. This code wouldn't solve it. Obviously I would just have to iterate the code as many times as columns as there are, so it goes right and left, but this would be really slow for huge labyrinths.

What do you think are good and efficient ways to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it recursively:

- `where_next` takes an array and location.  If it's in the last column, then it returns `True`.  Otherwise, it set's the current location to `1` and finds all adjacent locations that are `0` and recurses at that location.
- I initialize by running it over all `0` locations in the first column.

---

```
def where_next(a, i, j):
    a = a.copy()
    n, m = a.shape
    if j == 10:
        return True
    else:
        results = []
        a[i, j] = 1
        moves = [(i, j + 1), (i, j - 1), (i - 1, j), (i + 1, j)]
        for i_, j_ in moves:
            if (0 <= i_ < n) and (0 <= j < m):
                if a[i_, j_] == 0:
                    results.append(where_next(a, i_, j_))
        return any(results)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 11)))
a = df.values
any([where_next(a, i, 0) for i in np.where(a[:, 0] == 0)[0]])

True
```

---

```
print(df)

   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1
2   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1
4   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1
5   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1
6   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
8   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1
9   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0
```